# SQL group numbers that are 'close' together using a threshold value

Tags: sql

Consider the table:

```
id  value
1   2
2   4
3   6
4   9
5   10
6   12
7   19
8   20
9   22
```

I want to group them by a threshold value so that I can find values that are 'close' together.
To do this I want another column that groups these numbers together.  For this example use 2 as the
threshold.  The result should be like this.  It does not matter what is used as the group label, just 
as long as it makes it easy to query later.

```
id  value   group_label
1   2       A
2   4       A
3   6       A
4   9       B
5   10      B
6   12      B
7   19      C
8   20      C
9   22      C
```

Comment: which group would 8 be in? it's 2 away from 6 and 1 away from 9.

Comment: This is a data clustering problem. You may need an external tool to perform this (If you use Microsoft's stack, take a look at the data mining algorithms in Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services).

Comment: @FuzzyTree I think it would go into Group A and would also 'drag' `9,10 and 12` with it

Comment: @FuzzyTree yes I agree with LIUFA, it would connect those groups together.

Comment: rdbms spec would help.

Comment: Just to understand why I wanted to do this, here is a short explanation:  I had table of log in/out times for all given users.  A user could log in/out at anytime during a 'session' but I needed to group the login/logouts into a 'sessions' defined by a threshold value.  Thank you all for your help!  I remember this working out well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't get the version using `lag()` to work but here's a mysql query using variables

```
select id, value,
(case 
    when (value - @value) > 2
    then @groupLabel := @groupLabel + 1
    else @groupLabel
end) groupLabel, @value := value
from data cross join (
    select @value := -1, @groupLabel := 0
) t1
order by value
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5cd7e/8)

**Update**

Here's a query using `lag`

```
select t1.id, t1.value, count(t2.id)
from data t1 left join (
    select id, value,
    case when 
    (value - lag(value) over (order by value)) > 2
    then 1 else 0
    end groupLabel
    from data
) t2 on t2.groupLabel = 1
and t2.id <= t1.id
group by t1.id, t1.value
order by t1.value
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5cd7e/37)

Comment: Thanks FuzzyTree.  I put this in sqlfiddle but I got something I did not expect.  Is this what you were trying to do? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5cd7e/1

Comment: The example using lag is great, but an explanation would make it even better. For example, it would be worth explaining how count is used to generate group ids, because that's a bit clever.